# What React useCallback do when I pass. an object in first argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am fixing an infinite loop when using react with useEffect and useCallback.

```
const fetchApi =useCallback(()=>{
    setIsLoading(true)
      fetchDataFunction({
        resolve(res) {
          setFetchData(fromJS(res))
          setIsLoading(false)
        }
      })
},[param])
useEffect(()=>{
    fetchApi()
},[fetchApi])
```

It is causing an infinite loop. However, if I change the code as shown below

```
const fetchApi = useCallback({
    fetchApiFunc() {
      setIsLoading(true)
      fetchDataFunction({
        resolve(res) {
          setFetchData(fromJS(res))
          setIsLoading(false)
        }
      })
    }
  },[params])
  const { fetchApiFunc } = fetchApi
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApiFunc()
  }, [fetchApiFunc])
```

the problem is fixed. But I still do not understand what it does when the object in first params in useCallback.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem, rather than asking about your attempted solution, i think you should rather ask about your actual problem and what you are trying to solve .

Answer (score 0):

If you start using React-Hooks, and your component might need a life cycle method at some point. And, that is when you start using useEffect() (a.k.a Effect Hook). Then boom!!, you have encountered an infinite loop behavior, and you have no idea why the hell is that. If that happens, this article will explain to you why, and how can you prevent.

Where is the problem?
The “useEffect()”, will run after the initial render, then invoke the "fetchApiFunc()”.
Inside the   "fetchApiFunc()”, it will update the state “name” on line Then it will trigger the component to re-render again.
As a result, “useEffect()” will run again and update the state. Next, the whole process repeats again, and you're trapped inside an infinite loop.

“You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven’t changed between re-renders. To do so, pass an array as an optional second argument to useEffect”, from the official here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects